# Watson Java SDK speaker labels not working?

Tags: watson

Wondering if someone here could help me understand I'm having with the Java sdk and speaker labels...

The issue is that I enable speaker labels in the options, but they are almost always null (I've seen populated speaker labels only once). If I use exactly the same file in the watson's demo site I get very different results (most of the transcripts have a speaker label there).

The screenshoots attached show I'm enabling speaker labels:

[image: enabling speaker labels]

That they are null:

[image: null results]

And that the same file on the demo has labels:

[image: demo at watson]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the same result `speechResults.getSpeakerLabels();` always returns null. Were you able to figure out why?